# How to take whole available width in bootstrap css?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am basically a back-end developer who has very less information about the front end.

So basically I have left sidebar and right main content type layout in bootstrap. Now I want to take whole width remaining as a main content (total width- left sidebar width), in Bootstrap 3.

Any suggestion?

Comment: did you tried  <div class="container-fluid">  <div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 ">..</div></div>

Comment: edited question to make it more clear

Comment: add `display:block` to your element.

Comment: The BS3 grid always has a padding-left & padding-right of 15px so, you could go into the Bootstrap CSS file and modify all col-lg's to remove the padding-left & right. That then makes it full screen.

Comment: @K.B.M-thanks mate that was solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use grids, it is  simple. In short: your screen is divided in 12 columns and you say how much columns to occupy.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-3">
      Sidebar goes here
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-9">
      Main content
  </div>
</div>
```

Heads up: to be full screen width try put it as first child of the

Answer (score 0):

When Bootstrap is used, the class `col-**-12` will give full width. (where ** can be any size)

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid